# Choosing target installation path according to user selection on Inno Setup custom page

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I would like to create a custom Inno Setup page that will be displayed at the very beginning of installation, with three radio buttons to select from. That selection should set the value in `#define BinVer`. Currently I'm forced to make three separate installers, but I prefer to have just one with such feature. I'm setting it up like that for each exe:
`#define BinVer "111111"`, in another compilation I change it to `#define BinVer "222222"`, and finally I have `#define BinVer "333333"` for the third compilation. I'm using this define in such situations like that:

```pascal
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
begin
  case CurUninstallStep of
    usPostUninstall:
      begin
      CreateDir(ExpandConstant('{app}\bin\{#BinVer}\files'));
      end;
  end;
end;
```

or

```
Source: "{#CompPath}\Folder\sed.exe"; \
    DestDir: "{app}\bin\{#BinVer}\files\gui\unbound\"; Flags: deleteafterinstall
```

---

So far I have tried something like this, but it's just very beginning, not sure what to do next, I'm not that good with programming it:

```pascal
[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  Page: TInputOptionWizardPage;
begin
  Page := CreateInputOptionPage(wpWelcome, '', '', '', False, False);

  Page.AddEx('Radio button 1', 0, True);
  Page.AddEx('Radio button 2', 0, True);
  Page.AddEx('Radio button 3', 0, True);
end;
```

Also tried something like that (but I don't know if this is correct way to achieve this, it's not even compiling without errors):

```pascal
[Code]
var
  BinVer: string;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  Page: TInputOptionWizardPage;
begin
  Page :=
    CreateInputOptionPage(
      wpWelcome, 'Select BinVer', 'Select BinVer', '', False, False);
  Page.Add('BinVer 1', '111111');
  Page.Add('BinVer 2', '222222');
  Page.Add('BinVer 3', '333333');
  Page.DefaultValueIndex := 0; // initially select the first radio button
  Result := True;
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  Page: TInputOptionWizardPage;
begin
  Result := True;
  if CurPageID = wpWelcome then
  begin
    Page := GetInputOptionPage(wpWelcome);
    case Page.SelectedValueIndex of
      0: BinVer := '111111';
      1: BinVer := '222222';
      2: BinVer := '333333';
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change a value of a preprocessor variable (used on compile-time) on runtime.

But you do not have to. You want to use the value on runtime from Pascal Code. And you already have the value stored to runtime Pascal variable (`BinVer: string`). So use that:

```pascal
CreateDir(ExpandConstant('{app}\bin\' + BinVer + '\files'));
```

---

Though you do not really need to store the value to the global variable either. You can query the "InputOptionPage" when needed.

Example of full code, linking the selection to the `[Files]` section entry destination:

```
[Files]
Source: "{#CompPath}\Folder\sed.exe"; \
    DestDir: "{app}\bin\{code:GetBinVer}\files\gui\unbound\"; \
    Flags: deleteafterinstall
```

```pascal
[Code]

var
  InputOptionPage: TInputOptionWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  InputOptionPage := CreateInputOptionPage(wpWelcome, '', '', '', False, False);

  InputOptionPage.AddEx('Radio button 1', 0, True);
  InputOptionPage.AddEx('Radio button 2', 0, True);
  InputOptionPage.AddEx('Radio button 3', 0, True);
  // initially select the first radio button
  InputOptionPage.SelectedValueIndex := 0; 
end;

function GetBinVer(Param: string): string;
begin
  case InputOptionPage.SelectedValueIndex of
    0: BinVer := '111111';
    1: BinVer := '222222';
    2: BinVer := '333333';
    else RaiseException('Unexpected selection');
  end;
end;
```

*(not tested)*

Though linking it to a code in `CurUninstallStepChanged` is more complicated, that happens in another (uninstaller) process. So you will have to store the selection/`BinVer` somewhere (e.g. Windows Registry), where you will load it from in the uninstaller. You might by able to use [`SetPreviousData`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_setpreviousdata)/[`GetPreviousData`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getpreviousdata).